# Playing audio and video files when boat is in a gps position

Tags: video-player, localization, audio-player

We are looking for software that automatically plays audio and video files when the boat are entering a zone.

We operate a few shuttle boats and want to offer our guests visual and audio information about locations they pass by when on a boat trip.

Something open source that can run on a Raspberry pi is preferably, but an app on Android that can cast to a chromecast is also ok.

Anyone has a suggestion to any existing software that does this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear whether you want to play this on a fixed screen on the boat, like at TV or something, or you want to stream/push or otherwise play this on your guest's mobile devices. Please specify.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) can do that with [AutoLocation](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autolocation) and [AutoCast](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autocast) plugins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Theoretically the iPhone can do similar - but I wouldn't trust it to be accurate enough to be used as a tour guide.